# Unable to authenticate to mysql via vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have set up a MySQL server on Debian Linux and need to access a database on this server via vb.net. I found some help on Code Project to download the connector.net library and build a class to access the MySQL database. However when I try to connect I get the authentication error below when attempting to establish a connection with the mysql server:

Authentication to host '192.168.68.47' for user 'root' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'root'@'' (using password: YES)"}    System.Exception

It seems that the library is appending the Windows workstation and domain to the user name and I am getting error. I tried using the root user with "@IPaddress" of the workstation, but it simply appended the workstation name and domain to this user. I also tried with another user besides root.

Comment: for security you might not want to post the actual IP address...

Comment: thanks, noted for future posts ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is perfectly logic, because on your mysql server you need to Grant access to your host so it will be allowed to connect to, you can do it by following instructions in the following 
[Link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html)

Also in the mysql configuration file, in your case : `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` you need to delete the line

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

This line will restrict all access from remote hosts, deleting it will allow access from remote hose which is what you want to do.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi redaa, thanks for your quick reply. I have configured access to the MySQL server using the method you described, as I am able to access the MySQL server form the same workstation using Navicat for MySQL, which required setting up the user and configuring the MySQL for access from this workstation with the users mentioned.

Comment: @user3464761 what's the problem now ?

Comment: Okay, so I followed the instructions above to create another user with an "@workstation.domain" suffix and it worked beautifully. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @user3464761 you can upvote for the benifits of the community